# Changing Background music randomly by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want a script to change the background music randomly

this is the code  I tried , but it doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var BGM = [];
BGM[0] = "BGM/BGM1.mp3";
BGM[1] = "BGM/BGM2.mp3";
BGM[2] = "BGM/BGM3.mp3";
BGM[3] = "BGM/BGM4.mp3";
BGM[4] = "BGM/BGM5.mp3";
BGM[5] = "BGM/BGM5.mp6";

var idx = Math.round( Math.random() * 5 );

document.write("<embed src='"+BGM[idx]+"' autostart=true hidden=true         loop=true'>); 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What exactly did not work ?

Comment: Why don't you use the `audio` tag? IMHO you should try ``document.write(`<audio src=${BGM[idx]} ...></audio>`)``

Comment: Reference for having background music in website using javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394336/play-random-music

Comment: +giuscri it is easier for me to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a closing quote on your document.write call. Try:

```
document.write("<embed src='"+BGM[idx]+"' autostart=true hidden=true         loop=true'>");
```

Example: http://codepen.io/JasonGraham/pen/WxbZZo

Comment: Did i need to first create a tag in the html?

Comment: the tag of <embed>

Comment: You shouldn't need to, no! Document.write should both create, and insert the embed tag into your HTML. If you inspect the HTML in the example I provided via codepen, you should be able to see the embed tag is there :).